# Single word for driving/flying tank, submarine, and plane

Tags: single-word-requests

From a [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/3bp8b5/wp_there_is_a_secret_society_of_people_who_were/csocp7g):

> I have the training to **fly** thirteen different aircraft, two types of tanks, and a nuclear submarine.

*Fly* doesn't really work with tanks or submarines. What's the best way to properly state this sentence? Is there a good single word to replace *fly*, or do we have to say something like...

> I have the training to fly thirteen different aircraft, drive two types of tanks, and [whatever] a nuclear submarine.

Comment: *pilot* as a verb works.

Comment: @stevesliva worthwhile posting that as an answer. Just make sure to quote a dictionary when you do so. You'll get my +1, at least.

Comment: @stevesliva: I considered `pilot`; but the tank changed my mind.

Comment: @TusharRaj - I didn't think it was stretching the word too far if applying it to a list.  For tanks alone, yeah.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[handle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/handle#handle__16)** or **operate**

> 3. Drive or control (a vehicle): <sub>(Oxford)</sub>
>
> *he was going too fast and couldn’t handle the car*
>
> *From there you've got to learn to handle your ship and get to grips with the most difficult part - docking with the space station.*

Synonyms: **control, drive, steer, operate, manoeuvre, manipulate**

Comment: I'd say operate sounds better in this context

Comment: My first thought was "pilot" but that's not normal to say for a land vehicle. But "operate" works for all of them.

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest using **[pilot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pilot)** as a verb

```
verb (pilots, piloting, piloted)
1 Act as a pilot of (an aircraft or ship).

"He pilots 13 different types of vehicles, from airplanes to tanks and submarines."
```

Comment: With respect to aircraft, obviously, but also submarines, pilot (noun) is also exactly what the person is: e.g. http://www.insidejobs.com/careers/submarine-pilot

Comment: As for land vehicles, at least in Formula 1 the drivers are (sometimes) referred to as _pilots_ – maybe because they are flying low :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the changes to language over the centuries, each introduction of a word was possibly a new meaning, or a formation or borrowing from Greek or Latin. Except for common every day speech, I wouldn't hesitate to create new words; ancients had an easy time at this.

Can't find any Greek words that entered European languages but as for one from Latin, perhaps conduct.

Comment: Hello, empedocle, and thanks for visiting English Language & Usage. The question you are responding to asks for a single word that applies to "driving/flying tank, submarine, and plane." But your response, instead of suggesting a suitable word, discusses where English words come from. This is ultimately a comment and not an answer. Please try to limit your answer submissions to responses that directly answer posters' questions. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

**Operate.**

One operates machinery of all kinds. I believe it works with any type of vehicle. So, "I have the training to operate 13 different aircraft, two types of tanks, and a nuclear submarine."

Merriam-Webster:

> [*operate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/operate)
>         verb op·er·ate \ˈä-pə-ˌrāt, ˈä-ˌprāt\
>
> to function or behave in a proper or particular way
>     to use and control (something)
>     to have control of (something, such as a business, department, program, etc.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of Tushar Raj's answer. Please be more careful in the future